# possible to open secured Access 97 legacy database in Access 2016

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a password-protected Access 97 MDB for which we have a username and password. Is it possible to open the MDB in Access 2016 in order to run some queries against it?

Comment: I dont see why it wouldnt.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. Getting a not very descriptive error that it is not possible.

Comment: How about provide us that error?  Have you tried removing the password, on a copy, then trying to open it?  Edit your question please.

Answer (score 3):

Opening an Access 97 MDB file is no longer supported by Access 2013 and latter.

Access 2010 was the last version that can open an Access 97 MDB file.

Comment: That was going to be the question in my comment, so good - all the OP has to do is install Access 2010 and save a copy in the latest, for 2010, format etc.